Automatically Open GitHub Actions log group
With buildkite I can automtically open a log group by running echo "+++ A section of the build"
From: https://buildkite.com/docs/pipelines/managing-log-output
Is there an equivalent command for GitHub Actions?
I tried using buildkite's command echo "+++ A section of the build". Buildkite's implementation is based on their open source repo https://github.com/buildkite/terminal-to-html
